# What can be done on elements returned by elementsByXYZ?

Tags: intern

This question is about functional tests written with the Intern.

The elementsByXYZ methods returns an array of elements. I've noticed that I'm able to call the method click() on these returned elements, but I cannot for example call the method getAttribute(attributeName).

What is the list of methods that can be called on elements returned by a a elementsByXYZ method ?

Here is a code snippet that illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
        return this.remote
            .get(require.toUrl("./testpage.html"))
            .waitForCondition('ready', 5000)
            .elementById('widget1')
            .elementsByTagName('div')
            .then(function(children){
                    assert.equal(7, children.length, 'The expected number of children is wrong');
                    for(var i=0; i < 7; i++){
                        console.log(children[i].getAttribute('className'));
                        children[i].click();
                    }
            });
```

The console shows that children[i].getAttribute('className') returns undefined, while I can see that the clicks are correctly performed on each child.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you need to use something like:

```
elem.getAttribute('class', function (err, text) {
    console.log(text);
)};
```

When using wd.js? e.g. https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/jsonwire-mapping.md

```
getAttribute(element, attrName, cb) -> cb(err, value)
```

That works for me.